# How do I make a command run automatically when I open a new terminal window?

Tags: macos, terminal

How do I make a command run *automatically* (in my case: `alias t="todo.sh"`) whenever I open a new terminal window? I've looked for many posts but they all have personalised commands, which then led to personalised answers. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Look for shell startup files e.g. ~/.bashrc and ~/.zshrc etc There are many about this. All files are personalised each user has different ones. You are asking for a personalised one as well. There are many generic answers to this and the shell manuals give exact answers

Comment: Which specific posts have you looked at already?

Answer (score 1):

Each shell has initialisation files which get run at each start (aka new Terminal tab/window). Put the command into the appropriate one and it will be available in new tabs.

- for `bash`, use `~/.bashrc`
- for `zsh`, use `~/.zshrc`

You can use `echo $SHELL` to determine which shell you are using.